# Toolbar can't customize title text color

Tags: android, toolbar, androidx

I want to customize toolbar title text color dynamically.
I had tried following methods, but all methods below failed.
I had also tried to set color before running `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`, but still failed.
I had also searched and tried methods from Stack Overflow, but all also failed.

How can I do?

```kotlin
textColor = Color.parseColor("#00FF00")
toolbar.setTitleTextColor(textColour)
```

```kotlin
textColor = Color.parseColor("#00FF00")
(toolbar::class.java.getDeclaredField("mTitleTextView")
   .apply { isAccessible = true }
   .get(toolbar) as TextView)
   .setTextColor(textColour)
```

```xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:titleTextColor="#00FF00"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved that I read through source code of `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, when there is `CollapsingToolbarLayout` applied, should not change title text color with `Toolbar` function `setTitleTextColor()`, but with methods `setCollapsedTitleTextColor()` and `setExpandedTitleColor()` of `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.
Following is my code.

- In activity

```kotlin
val textColor = Color.parseColor("#00FF00")
collapsingToolbarLayout.setExpandedTitleColor(textColor)
collapsingToolbarLayout.setCollapsedTitleTextColor(textColor)
```

- In xml layout

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="270dp"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
    app:toolbarId="@id/toolbar"
    android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout">
    ...
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
    ...
</com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```